# Web MIDI API on Windows 10 does not list MIDI devices that are in use by another program

Tags: web-midi

I am using [navigator.requestMIDIAccess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/requestMIDIAccess) to query all MIDI devices connected to a Windows 10 computer. A MIDI device will not appear in the callback's `midiAccess.inputs` or `midiAccess.outputs` if another program, such as a DAW, is connected to it. I understand Windows will not allow you to open one MIDI port multiple times, but I would like to see all MIDI devices connected to the Windows computer in the array of inputs & outputs.

Is there a different call I should make to query for all connected MIDI devices?
This is possible using [UWP DeviceInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation?view=winrt-22621), but I would like to be able to do this using web technologies since I am creating a react/nodejs app.